# Display VFpage content on Facebook

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites, facebook

Is it possible to display the contents of a VFpage accessible on a public Site on to Facebook as a section?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can:

Setup > Develop > Sites,

Register your Force.com sub-domain name,

Create new Force.com Site

next to 'Site Visualforce Pages' click Edit
add your page to the list of Enabled Visualforce Pages

[Check SFDC Sites Documentation Here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sites_overview.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2F&type=5)